# Xcode: cannot build ParseFacebookUtilsV4 (Cocoapods)

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods, facebook-login

I installed ParseFacebookUtilsV4 using Cocoapods, but I'm having some problems in using the framework. When I try to import it in AppDelegate Xcode returns me the error:

```
Could not build Objective-C module 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
```

The error, in PFUV4, is

```
'Bolts/BFTask.h' file not found
```

This is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'Cashy' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.10'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.10'
  pod 'Parse', '~> 1.13'
  pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~> 1.11'
end
```

I found some similar issues caused by #import <"framework"> statement (replace by #import "module.h"). But if I try to solve this way, I should replace the statement one million times (all Parse, PFUV4 and so on files!).

Do you have some suggestions to fix this? I've done it thousands of time but now with Xcode 7.3 it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of you using use_frameworks!

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'Cashy' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.10'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.10'
  pod 'Parse', '~> 1.13'
  pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4', '~> 1.11'
end
```

Comment: But I'm using Swift, so I uncommented it as explained in the comment below

Comment: The pod of ParseFacebookUtilsV4 is not compatible to build as module. There could be conflicts when you try to add other libraries. I used to have the same issue before. so for other swift frameworks i used Carthage and used Pods to include incompatible framework libraries.

Comment: Refer to this for more details - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4420